# when i run lsnrctl start prod following error comes

Tags: oracle, database-administration

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 02-OCT-2016 13:08:28

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /oraeng/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /home/oracle/listener.ora
Log messages written to /oraeng/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/log/diag/tnslsnr/oracle/prod/alert/log.xml
TNS-01150: The address of the specified listener name is incorrect

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...

Comment: rane =
        (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =192.168.246.128)(PORT =1521 ))
                )
        )
    )
        SID_LIST_rane=
        (SID_LIST=
        (SID_DESC=
                (SID_NAME = raneesh)
        (ORACLE_HOME =/oraeng/app/oracle/product/11.2.0 )
)
)

Comment: this is listener file